# reshape2 returning "Error in .fun(.value[0], ...) : 3 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1"

Tags: r, r-markdown, data-science, tidyverse, reshape2

KEY aim: *To calculate the mean abundance of each species at each site, from three replicate samples per site*
KEY variables: Site.Number, Replicate, species.

I have replicate samples which need to be combined as a single sample unit for statistical analysis. The two microhabitats which were sampled have been divided into two separate frames, allowing for the data frames to be reduced to site number, habitat type, replicate number, and the 197 species:

```
sev.mci.bank <- group_by(sev.mci.banklog[sev.mci.banklog$Habitat == "Bank Sweeps", ])
sev.mci.log <- group_by(sev.mci.banklog[sev.mci.banklog$Habitat == "Log Wash", ])
```

I am then trying to use reshape2 to average the replicate samples in order to reduce the number of samples of each species per site from three to one, by first rearranging the species data into single column form.

```
library(reshape2)
as.data.frame(sev.mci.bank)

column.bank <- melt(sev.mci.bank, id=c('Site.Number', 'Habitat', 'Replicate'))
```

## This works fine, but then..

```
mean.bank <- acast(column.bank, Site.Number + Habitat ~ variable, value='value', FUN=mean)
```

## running this code returns

```
"Error in .fun(.value[0], ...) : 3 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1""
```

Please help! I can't figure out where to go from here. I initially tried to use tidyverse to do this, any recommendations are welcome.
The code for this was found at [rbloggers.com](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-for-ecologists-creating-a-site-x-species-matrix/)

My code in full:

```
sev.mci.banklog <- read.csv ("/Users/Chloe/Desktop/Environmental Data Analysis/EDA.working.directory/SEVMCI_data_bank_log.csv")

sev.mci.bank <- group_by(sev.mci.banklog[sev.mci.banklog$Habitat == "Bank Sweeps", ])
sev.mci.log <- group_by(sev.mci.banklog[sev.mci.banklog$Habitat == "Log Wash", ])

library(reshape2)
as.data.frame(sev.mci.bank)
head(sev.mci.bank)

column.bank <- melt(sev.mci.bank, id=c('Site.Number', 'Habitat', 'Replicate'))
mean.bank <- dcast(column.bank, Site.Number + Habitat ~ variable, value='value', FUN=mean)
```

My data:
[link to .csv](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmagKxVfx5LXnwlDQTuNVm-luWqM)

Thank you!

Comment: Please include data and code as plain text (_e.g._ using dput), not images, so other users can copy/paste it.

Comment: Just include a minimal amount of data, the smallest you can get away with that shows the problem.

Comment: Data is attached as download link, the file will download as the .csv document. @neilfws I am new to Stackoverflow & newish to R, not sure how to use dput! I hope the edits help :) all code can now be pasted into R.

Comment: Can you explain what mean you want to calculate? Is it by site and habitat (all species) or by site, habitat and species?

Comment: @neilfws I am trying to calculate the mean species abundance per site (per species), the means will come from the three replicate samples at each site. Habitat is not a worry as I have separated the habitat types into two different tables, so will run the same code on them individually- the key is to reduce the samples at each site from three to one. Does that make sense?

Comment: eg. site 2529 has replicates 1 (0), 2 (0) & 3 (2) for Acarina. So that would turn into one sample, of abundance (1.5) ((0+0+2)/3). To complicate further, it would be ideal to round down each mean score to the nearest whole number, but thats another ball game!

Comment: OK, but you mean (0 + 0 + 2) / 3 = 0.67 for Acarina, right? And site 7529.

Comment: Jesus, yes, can you tell I'm R fried at the moment :') thank you so so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you want to calculate mean species count by site number and habitat. In that case, try this `tidyverse` approach.

You can then use *e.g.* `%>% filter(Habitat == "Bank Sweeps")` to subset the results.

```
library(tidyverse) # provides readr, dplyr, tidyr

SEVMCI_data_bank_log <- read_csv("/Users/Chloe/Desktop/Environmental Data Analysis/EDA.working.directory/SEVMCI_data_bank_log.csv")

bank_mean <- SEVMCI_data_bank_log %>% 
  gather(species, count, -Replicate, -Habitat, -`Site Number`) %>% 
  group_by(`Site Number`, Habitat, species) %>% 
  summarise(mean_count = mean(count))

bank_mean

# A tibble: 1,970 x 4
# Groups:   Site Number, Habitat [?]
   `Site Number` Habitat     species        mean_count
           <int> <chr>       <chr>               <dbl>
 1          7171 Bank Sweeps Acanthophlebia      0.   
 2          7171 Bank Sweeps Acarina             0.667
 3          7171 Bank Sweeps Acroperla          43.3  
 4          7171 Bank Sweeps Aeshna              0.   
 5          7171 Bank Sweeps Alloecentrella      0.   
 6          7171 Bank Sweeps Ameletopsis         0.   
 7          7171 Bank Sweeps Amphipoda           5.33 
 8          7171 Bank Sweeps Ampullariidae       0.   
 9          7171 Bank Sweeps Anisopodidae        0.   
10          7171 Bank Sweeps Anisops             0.   
# ... with 1,960 more rows
```

Comment: This is perfect, hugely appreciate your help @neilfws! I started out with tidyverse and should have stuck with it. Have recently been taught the pipes syntax for dplyr but practice will make perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. Please vote & accept answer if it solved the issue.